# iOS- Swift How can I make this type of Bar to play with the video?. I am using Avplayer to play video

Tags: ios, swift, video, controls

[This Image represents what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj7WJ.png)

I am playing video in a view using avplayer and i want this type of bar which shows the video playing progress.
I have gotten video thumbnails and put them in a horizontal collectionview. I just want to know how I can make the collectionview to scroll automatically with respect to video progress.

Answer (score 1):

first you should have to get images from video likes this

```
var videoUrl:URL // use your own url
var frames:[UIImage] = [] {
   didSet {
      progressView.images = frames
   }
}
private var generator:AVAssetImageGenerator!

lazy var progressView:PlainHorizontalProgressBar = {
        let progressView = PlainHorizontalProgressBar()
        progressView.images = frames
        return progressView
  }()

func getAllFrames() {
   let asset:AVAsset = AVAsset(url:self.videoUrl)
   let duration:Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
   self.generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset:asset)
   self.generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
   self.frames = []
   for index:Int in 0 ..< Int(duration) {
      self.getFrame(fromTime:Float64(index))
   }
   self.generator = nil
}

private func getFrame(fromTime:Float64) {
    let time:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, preferredTimescale:600)
    let image:CGImage
    do {
       try image = self.generator.copyCGImage(at:time, actualTime:nil)
    } catch {
       return
    }
    self.frames.append(UIImage(cgImage:image))
}
```

then make custom progressView

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PlainHorizontalProgressBar: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .gray {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    var images:[UIImage] = [] {
        didSet {
//            how much images you want to show on progress bar let suppose 11
            for i in 0...10 {
                 let imageView = UIImageView()
                imageView.image = images[i]
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: Double(i * 20), y: Double(0), width: 20, height: self.frame.height)
                self.addSubview(imageView)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    private let progressLayer = CALayer()
    private let backgroundMask = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayers()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupLayers()
    }

    private func setupLayers() {
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundMask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.height * 0.25).cgPath
        layer.mask = backgroundMask

        let progressRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: rect.width * progress, height: rect.height))

        progressLayer.frame = progressRect
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

after that create progressView in class

Comment: Will this imageview bar animate with respect to video?

Comment: i have given you an idea how you can do it. just put some effort and achieve your goal. if you wanna go more deep then you should explore more video tutorials